# jQuery isn't working. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have embedded jQuery into my doc but for some reason it is not sending an alert can anyone help. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

    if (jQuery) {

        alert('jQuery is installed');

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Try if ($) { alert('jQuery is installed'); }
Could also be the capital Q

Comment: Post a complete code example please. What error do you get?

Comment: I'm going to say you are getting no error and @Nick the correct way to call jQuery is with a capital Q.

Comment: If you put the jquery file in the HTML then why do you need to test if it's installed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have to make a separate script tag for external resources. Please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (jQuery) {

        alert('jQuery is installed');

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @scribblemaniac, you are the man. Do I have to keep using the <script type="text/javascript" every time or just list it after the script tags?

Comment: @JayKhalifa The `type="text/javascript"` is not even necessary with HTML5, but if you are following previous conventions, it is a good idea to put it in every opening script tag.